# Como definir o valor de inicialização de um campo PRIMARY KEY definido como IDENTITY no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

No MySQL quando se cria uma tabela com um campo AUTO_INCREMENT sendo ele PRIMARY KEY é possível definir qual será o valor de inicialização do primeiro registro do mesmo, como segue o script abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_exemplo` (
  `id_exemplo` int(11) primary key auto_increment NOT NULL,
  `nm_exemplo` varchar(100),
  `dt_registrado` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dt_alterado` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Sendo assim o primeiro registro dessa tabela ira começar com 5 como valor do campo `id_exemplo`, e dele em diante.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como seria possível fazer isso no SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linha que define esse campo seria algo como:

```
[id_exemplo] [int] IDENTITY(5,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
-- IDENTITY(x,y) em que x é o primeiro valor e y o incremento para cada novo registo
```